Is it Possible to Create and Apply a New Search Facet Type in BigCommerce?
We have a BigCommerce enterprise store that uses custom fields for product filters. I'm wondering if there's a way to create and apply a new facet type to the product filters sidebar? We sell footwear and the current checkbox list format of \templates\components\faceted-search\facets\multi.html doesn't work very well for Shoe Sizes. Shoes Sizes would best be displayed in a selectable block style grid like the one below.

The trouble is that a selectable block style grid doesn't work so well for things with longer descriptions like Product Features. My dilemna is that I need two different types of multi.html and I need to be able to pick and choose which one is applied to a given product filter. For example, Shoes Size would have multi-custom.html applied while Product Features would have multi.html applied. The end result would be something like the following mockup

Is it possible to create a new custom facet type like mult-custom.html and somehow selectively apply it to my Shoes Size custom field? Thank you in advance for your help!

No, there's not a way to add an additional type, but you could write conditional statements in multi.html, for example "if title == 'Shoe Size'  " then style like this, else style as default
